# PHP mail not showing senders email in from header frfom HTML form

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Please could someone assist me in showing the senders email in the from header on the email. Please see code below, currently when i receive the email it shows the to email address in the from and the to.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Form submission</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="mail_handler.php" method="post">
First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name"><br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
Message:<br><textarea rows="5" name="message" cols="30"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "bestwayhomemaintenance@gmail.com"; 
    $from = $_POST['email']; 
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $subject = "Form submission";
    $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
    $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

    //$headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers = "From: $to \r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $from \r\n";
    //$headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    //mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
    
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send from a gmail address unless you're sending through gmail's servers, which essentially means you can't use PHP's mail() function to do it. You may be able to try, but your messages will be marked as forgeries.

To set the envelope sender with the mail function, you need to use a `-f` parameter in the `$additional_params` parameter in the mail function.

Your script is vulnerable to header injection attacks, and it is also exploitable for cross-site scripting.

To avoid the forgery issue, I recommend sending directly through gmail, which mean you need to use SMTP, and the easiest way to do that is to [use PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) that you tagged this question with. Base your code on the examples provided with it.

Comment: Thank you for the response, Just to clarify, when using PHPMailer will it then show the users email address that they entered into the html form in the email From header?

Comment: Ive downloaded composer, do i need the github files aswell? If i do, where do i save them after downloading them?

Comment: You can't have the submitter's address as the from address – that's the forgery that will cause delivery problems. The usual way to work around this in contact forms is to put  your own address in the From address, but add the submitter's address in a Reply-to – see [the contact form example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/contactform.phps).

Comment: composer is a tool you install on your own system, and it downloads dependencies (such as PHPMailer) and creates an autoloader so that you don't have to worry about loading the files yourself. When you run `composer require phpmailer/phpmailer`, composer will download PHPMailer into the `vendor` folder. In your script you then `require 'vendor/autoload.php'`, and it will deal with loading the PHPMailer files automatically as they are needed. You can then upload the whole lot to your hosting server – you don't have to run composer on your server.

Comment: I am using your code and it gave me the error "Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again later." What could have possibly gone wrong? Where should i look?

Comment: There are lots of ways things can go wrong! If you read the code in that example, it mentions `$mail->ErrorInfo`; append that to your error message, and it will tell you why it failed. You can also set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;` for lots of debug output. Beyond that, read [the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).